# SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: java, android, nginx, ssl

Getting back to Android after a while. I just purchased an EV certificate and am trying to connect using SSL/TSL to my web service. I'm getting:

```
2021-07-23 09:52:12.009 26190-26225/xx.xx.wb5000dispenser E/xx.xx.wb5000dispenser.service.DispenseServiceImpl: Error registering site
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:286)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:472)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at xx.xx.wb5000dispenser.service.DispenseServiceImpl.callPost(DispenseServiceImpl.java:72)
        at xx.xx.wb5000dispenser.service.DispenseServiceImpl.registerSite(DispenseServiceImpl.java:50)
        at xx.xx.wb5000dispenser.service.Wb5000Service$DailyRegisterThread.run(Wb5000Service.java:57)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x9fa470c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242 0x9d1e6f1b:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
            ... 16 more
```

I found on one of the answers here that I should try testssl.sh. I installed that and here's some of the report...

```
...
Testing protocols via sockets except NPN+ALPN 

 SSLv2      not offered (OK)
 SSLv3      not offered (OK)
 TLS 1      not offered
 TLS 1.1    not offered
 TLS 1.2    offered (OK)
 TLS 1.3    offered (OK): final
 NPN/SPDY   http/1.1 (advertised)
 ALPN/HTTP2 http/1.1 (offered)
...
 Rating (experimental) 

 Rating specs (not complete)  SSL Labs's 'SSL Server Rating Guide' (version 2009q from 2020-01-30)
 Specification documentation  https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide
 Protocol Support (weighted)  100 (30)
 Key Exchange     (weighted)  90 (27)
 Cipher Strength  (weighted)  90 (36)
 Final Score                  93
 Overall Grade                A
 Grade cap reasons            Grade capped to A. HSTS is not offered
```

Let me know if it would be useful to see more...

I looked on the server (nginx hosted on AWS) and there were no errors in the log during this period.

Here is the creation of the SSL context:

```
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating SSL context", ex);
    }
```

TSLv1.3 failed as unsupported.

Here is my connection code:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytesToSend.length);

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream()); //Exception here
        out.write(bytesToSend);
        out.flush();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        result = readStreamAsString(in);
    }
   catch(Exception exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error registering site", exception);
        throw new Square1Exception("Error hitting:" + urlName, exception);
    }
```

Blows up as indicated on the creation of the output stream.

My tablet is running Android 9, which is much newer than most of the similar issues I've found.

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Did you try setting Tls version on client? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-do-i-change-default-ssl-protocol-my-java-client-application-will-use

Comment: Where are setting SSLContext?

Comment: Hard to tell without being able to test the site myself. Common problems though with this kind of error: a firewall or captive portal is causing problems, the domain has IPv4 and IPv6 records but only IPv4 is properly setup for HTTPS, the client does not access the same IP address as the test does (different DNS resolver) and thus the test from testssl.sh does not reflect what happens at the client.

Comment: Added SSL context. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Thom: I cannot see any problems with the site. The [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) does not show any problems either. Can you access the site from the browser on the same tablet?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes I can. Interesting.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The last bit was a URL port problem. I fixed it and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Joy and alexrait, the problem was not specifying the SSL context. Evidently, android doesn't try the best ones by default. :(

So, I added the code here:

```
    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating SSL context", ex);
    }
```

And then added this line to use it:

```
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

And now everything seems to be working properly. Thanks for the help.